# If I lose 90 day currency can I fly at night at all?

Tags: faa-regulations, night-flying, currency

Specifically [14 CFR 61.57 (a) (2)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61/section-61.57#p-61.57(a)(2)) states:

> For the purpose of meeting the requirements of paragraph (a)(1) of this section, a person may act as a pilot in command of an aircraft under day VFR or day IFR, provided no persons or property are carried on board the aircraft, other than those necessary for the conduct of the flight.

But the exception allowing a person to act as pilot in command without currency DOES NOT exist for night VFR nor night IFR. Therefore, can a person act as pilot in command at night while regaining currency? Can you even fly solo when you have lost your currency?

Comment: For those not familiar with it offhand, what are "the requirements of paragraph (a)(1)"? Please post or link to the specific reg. Thanks, and welcome to Av.SE.

Answer (score 2):

61.57(a)(2) only applies to regaining currency if you are flying a plane that requires more than one pilot crewmember. It allows a non-current pilot to *act as PIC* when it would otherwise be illegal in order to make it easier for a non-current pilot to regain currency. It has no relevance to a solo pilot in a plane certificated for a single pilot, since 61.57(a)(1) does not forbid a non-current pilot from acting as PIC in a plane certificated for a single pilot as long as they are not carrying passengers.

61.57(a)(1) forbids you from acting as PIC if you are carrying passengers *or* if the plane requires a multi-member crew:

> "Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, no person may act as a pilot in command of an aircraft *carrying passengers* or of an aircraft certificated for *more than one pilot flight crewmember* unless that person has made at least three takeoffs and three landings within the preceding 90 days, and—"

emphasis mine.

61.57(a)(2) allows you to operate during the day with additional required crewmembers, as long as  you aren't carrying passengers or property. This makes it easier to regain currency once you have lost it if you are flying a plane that requires multiple pilot crewmembers.

61.57(b)(1) is different in that it only forbids you from acting as PIC at night if you are carrying passengers. It contains the same language as 61.57(a)(1): "[...]no person may act as pilot in command of an aircraft *carrying passengers*[...]" (emphasis mine), but it does *not* have the bit about aircraft certificated for more than one pilot crewmember. Since it doesn't have this restriction, it doesn't need a similar exception.

Comment: OK, this popped back up to the top and I reread it again... I am loath to get into another protracted discussion, but I don't see the truth in your opening statement: "*61.57(a)(2) **only** applies to regaining currency if you are flying a plane that requires more than one pilot crewmember.*" Can you remind me how you arrived at this conclusion? (2) follows (1), which makes it clear that "general experience" under (a) applies to carrying passengers, **OR** acting as PIC in a plane requiring more than one pilot.

Comment: @MichaelHall Even if 61.57(a)(2) did not exist, it would be legal for a non-current pilot flying a single-pilot aircraft to act as PIC (solo) and regain lost day currency. But it would be illegal for a non-current pilot flying a multi-pilot aircraft to act as PIC of a multi-pilot crew. 61.57(a)(2) *allows* such a pilot to act as PIC. It doesn't *require* anything- the language used is permissive ("may", not "must"). It isn't helpful for a pilot who can just solo the aircraft since it comes with extra restrictions.

Comment: OK, we are back to where I punted before... But, I still don't agree with your conclusion that (2) applies to multi pilot only:  "*it would be legal for a non-current pilot flying a single-pilot aircraft to act as PIC (solo) and regain lost day currency.*"  Yes, this I agree with.  And that is exactly what (2) says - while pointing out that you cannot carry passengers until you do so.  The restriction on not carrying passengers while acting as PIC if you aren't current applies to both single and multi pilot aircraft, does it not?

Comment: The way I interpret the intent of this section WRT to multi-pilot operations is that you "may" act as PIC if you aren't carrying passengers.  However, if you are carrying passengers, you can still regain landing currency as sole manipulator, but there must be another pilot acting as PIC in the aircraft.  Single pilot cannot carry passengers while acting as PIC if they aren't current, period.  Do you agree with this?

Comment: You said "*But it would be **illegal** for a non-current pilot flying a multi-pilot aircraft to act as PIC of a multi-pilot crew.*"  No, it would actually be **legal** "*provided no persons or property are carried on board the aircraft, other than those necessary for the conduct of the flight.*"  That is the exact verbatim caveat per section (2).

Comment: @MichaelHall It would be illegal **if** 61.57(a)(2) **did not exist**, as I said. The point of 61.57(a)(2) is to make exactly this operation legal. It has no effect on single pilot operations because the equivalent single pilot operation (solo flight with no passengers- cargo is allowed) is already legal even without it.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for "if X did not exist". It does exist. Interpretation of its intent is the central theme here.  I'm not seeing any clarification that might come from temporarily ignoring what it says.

Comment: @MichaelHall The discussion is about what purpose 61.57(a)(2) serves. Understanding what it changes (i.e. the difference between "if X did not exist" and "X exists") is key to understanding its intent. To whit, if 61.57(a)(2) did not exist, *nothing* would be different for a single pilot operation. This is the sense in which I mean 61.57(a)(2) only applies to multi pilot operations. It only gives some rights that single pilots *already have* to multi pilot operations.

Comment: I agree that (2) isn't really necessary because the requirement to get current again is implied in (1), but you cannot say that (2) does not apply to single piloted aircraft because it clearly states "*For the purpose of meeting the requirements of paragraph (a)(1) of this section...*"  Section (a)(1) includes all aircraft.  If the intent was that (2) only applies to multi-pilot aircraft it would instead say "*For the purpose of **aircraft certificated for more than one pilot flight crewmember** meeting the requirements of paragraph (a)(1) of this section...*"

Comment: @MichaelHall We agree that it has no *relevance* to a single pilot, yes? And that it has relevance to a pilot of an aircraft certificated for more than one pilot flight crewmember? Obviously the law doesn't vanish for you if you're flying solo, but it is also completely irrelevant for you.

Comment: I agree that (2) isn't necessary to understand the requirement to get current, but it is applicable to a single pilot, and as such, is relevant.  So I guess it depends on how you define "relevance"!  ;)  A single pilot still must perform the landings "*under day VFR or day IFR, provided no persons or property are carried on board the aircraft, other than those necessary for the conduct of the flight.*"  Yes, you comply when you are solo.  Yes, it's kinda redundant and not really needed.  However, there is no exemption made for single piloted aircraft.

Comment: @MichaelHall No, a solo pilot can perform landings with cargo and at night if they like. That's my *whole* point. 61.57(a)(2) says that a pilot *may* act as PIC under those conditions, not that they *must* follow those conditions any time they act as PIC. It's an *extra* path to regaining currency, not the *only* one. A solo pilot outside of currency reads 61.57(a)(1), sees that they are not "carrying passengers" or flying an "aircraft certificated for more than one pilot flight crewmember," and so they can act as PIC, day or night. They read 61.57(b)(1) and see they aren't carrying passengers

Comment: so they can act as PIC at night. Once they've done 3 night landings to a full stop, they read 61.57(a)(1) again. They see they have made "three takeoffs and landings within the preceding three days," and so they are day current. They read 61.57(b)(1) again and see that they are also night current.

Comment: At no point did they need to reference 61.57(a)(2), as they weren't carrying passengers or flying an aircraft certificated for more than one pilot crewmember. And so they didn't need the *extra* permission that 61.57(a)(2) gives pilots to act as PIC when they *aren't* solo, so long as they only bring required crewmembers, fly in the day, and don't carry cargo.

Comment: "a single pilot still *must*" Where do you see the word *must* in 61.57(a)(2)?

Comment: "Must" is not in (2).  I meant *must* in the context of (must have) "*made at least three takeoffs and three landings within the preceding 90 days*" as required in (1).  Anyway, use of the word "may" in (2) muddies things in my opinion, but I stand by my assertion that (2) does not specifically or implicitly exclude single piloted aircraft.  And with that, I will punt...  (my mind is dead and my fingers are numb, but I respect your knowledge and would happily buy beers to chat more if you are ever in the Seattle area...)  Cheers.

Comment: @MichaelHall Might take you up on that if I'm ever in the area. Cheers!